# C# listbox.selectedItem. Как получить выделенную строку считанную из бд access

Tags: c#, sql, access, listbox

```
Всем привет. Ребята, помогите разобраться. Начал изучать с#. Задача написать программу которая будет считывать информацию (база access) в listbox и ( самое главное) при выделении строки , получить эту строку ( знаю что это делается с помощью selectedItem), что бы совершать с ней какие нить операции.
```

{    namespace TEMP
        {
            public partial class Form1 : Form
            {
                public string sqlQuet = "SELECT [Name Sections] FROM [List of Partition Engine Room]",
                  connectionPathBD = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\TEMP\MarinePart\buck up\MeriTime\Common.mdb";

```
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQuet, connectionPathBD);
                DataSet DS = new DataSet();

                DA.Fill(DS, "[List of Partition Engine Room]");
                listBox1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            }

         private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Здесь надо прописать что-то, что будет считывать строку  через
listBox1.selectItem;
        }
        } 
    }
```

}

Comment: Вопрос в чем? Вы дали не пойми какой код и написали "Я новичок, есть задача написать программу, которая будет выводить данные из базы и при выделение элемента получать строку", ок, задача есть, но вопрос то в чем, что у вас не получается, что делает код предоставленный вами, что от нас хотите то?

Comment: [Видосик](https://youtu.be/uONQaT-nwls) в тему.

Comment: Уважаемый, читайте внимательней!!! Вопрос не ясен? Я дал код в котором подключена база данных. Она выводиться в listbox. Но получить строку не могу. Не получается! Что не ясно? Мне надо что бы в переменную сохранялась срока которая будет выделена в листбоксе, которая считывается из базы данных. Прежде чем эмоционировать, почитайте вопрос внимательно. И да, от вас, точно ничего не хочу, потому как вы не помогать пытаетесь, а показать какой вы крутой програмер и как чайники убогие вас нервируют.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, нужно заключить в кавычки путь к базе данных, так как он содержит пробелы:

```
Data Source = \"C:\\TEMP\\MarinePart\\buck up\\MeriTime\\Common.mdb\"
```

Кавычки экранированы: `\"`.

Также можно использовать одинарные кавычки. Их не нужно экранировать:

```
Data Source = 'C:\\TEMP\\MarinePart\\buck up\\MeriTime\\Common.mdb'
```

---

Во-вторых, провайдер Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 давным-давно устарел. Он использовался с версиями Access 97-2003.

Для более новых версий Аксеса используется провайдер Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0.

---

В-третьих, если есть сомнения по поводу того, как правильно записать строку соединения, то следует использовать специальный класс для её конструирования:

```
var builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
builder.DataSource = "C:\\TEMP\\MarinePart\\buck up\\MeriTime\\Common.mdb";

string connectionString = builder.ToString();
```

Билдер автоматически сделает экранирование, где нужно.

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку. Все же вопрос в получении строки остается открытым.